# First order quasilinear Partial Differential Equation methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What methods, not including the one of characteristic curves and surfaces, can I use to solve first-order quasilinear equations like this one?
$$u_x+u_y=u^2$$

Comment: Change of coordinates.

Comment: @Famous Blue Raincoat:  you mean like using $s = x + y$, $t = x - y$; then doesn't $u_x + u_y$ become $u_s$ so we have $u_s = u^2$ etc.?

Comment: @RobertLewis  Yes, that's what I meant. It's characteristics in disguise, but textbooks may treat  it as a separate method.

Comment: @Famous Blue Raincoat:  thought so, had the same feel.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=1$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=t+y_0=x+y_0$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=u^2$ , we have $u(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{f(y_0)-t}=\dfrac{1}{f(y-x)-x}$

Comment: ...not including the one of characteristic curves and surfaces...